# svc, xml are not being deployed

Tags: wcf, msbuild

I'm having problem with publishing WCF service from CI (Cruise Control)..

Let's say I have a WCF project called  "WCF-A". I put the following lines in csproj of "WCF-A"

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="##############Before build##################" Importance="high" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="publish" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="##############After build##################$(OutputFolder)" Importance="high" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectName).csproj" Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication" Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=publish\;OutDir=publish\bin\" />
</Target>
```

I'm using the following to build my service from commandline. (Note that we are using CI but in order to make my question simple, I will use commandline. )

```
E:\..\Code\>msbuild MyServices.sln /t:Clean;Rebuild
```

It works perfectly and all assemblies, cross-domain xml, svc files are published under "publish" folder.

The problem come out when I add another services (let's called it "WCF-B") in the solution file. **[Edit]** I added the same "BeforeBuild" and "AfterBuild" in WCF-B as well. **[/Edit]** I project-referenced WCF-A from "WCF-B"... but when I build the solution with the same command that I used, the publishing for "WCF-B" is working fine. But the cross-domain file and svc file of "WCF-A" are not being deployed anymore. Only assembly of "WCF-A" are being published under "publish\bin" folder.

Do you guys have any idea why it's happening like that? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

**I think having "project-reference" creates this problem**.. But I need to project-reference instead of calling the service from proxy class. Since both services will be hosted on the same server, I prefer dll-reference over service-calls.

Comment: Did you add the same `BeforeBuild` and `AfterBuild` targets to your WCF-B service?

Comment: Yes. I added the same code that I posted in WCF-B as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the files of WCF-A are being deleted by the `BeforeBuild` target of WCF-B (assuming that the *publish* directory resolves to the same directory) and that the assembly WCF-A cannot be deleted because it is referenced by WCF-B and in use.

You might try to increase the log verbosity using `/v:d` or even `/v:diag` for further information.

```
E:\..\Code\>msbuild MyServices.sln /t:Clean;Rebuild /v:d
```

Comment: My guess is that when MSBuild or the task that I added might detect that WCF-A is being referenced by WCF-B. So, it doesn't treat WCF-A as a web service project and it treat WCF-A as class library so that it generate only dll without coping svc files. What do you think? Or, Am I in wrong direction?

Comment: the length of commandline is limited.. would be great if log are written in file.. :)

Comment: ok.. I'm trying with this command E:\Code\trunk\Silverlight\Services>msbuild Memolife.Services.sln /t:Clean;Rebuil
d /v:d /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MyLog.log

Comment: As long as you didn't change any of WFC-A's settings, MSBuild should not treat it any differently just because you're referencing its output somewhere else. Does the WCF-A still show the web service project icon in Visual Studio Solution Explorer?